# Where do you restore the users In-App Purchases?

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, billing

I've been following the garbage Google tutorial but it doesn't mention where to put the code to restore a users purchases. In the TD tutorial it writes:

```
try {
  mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
} catch (IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
  complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
}
```

in the `startSetup()` method, is this what I write and where I put it?

Comment: *garbage Google tutorial* lol. Is it a typo or ?

Comment: No, the guide on IAP's are atrocious and make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve information about purchases made by a user at any place in your app.

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
   String continuationToken =
      ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

   for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
      String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
      String signature = signatureList.get(i);
      String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

      // do something with this purchase information
      // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
   }

   // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
   // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
}
```

You can use this code where ever you want to restore a user purcahse

Comment: Is the way I say showed not the recommended way? I saw the way you did it but in an older guide.

Comment: getPurchases() is the API to get the purchased items bundle. It's up to you how you how you use the bundle.

Comment: before you re-responded, I used onQuery and: `Purchase lessonOnePurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_bl1);
            isPurchased_basiclesson1 = (lessonOnePurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(lessonOnePurchase));` instead, is this an issue?

Comment: not at all! This how you can you can use where ever you want.